# Cannot declare generic function possibly returns null

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic function that will return either an object of the generic type or null (and possibly undefined), so I added `| null | undefined` to the return type but it doesn't seem to get applied:

```
const test = <T>(obj: TypeA<T>): T | undefined | null => {
  return someObject[obj];
};
```

When I look at the generated definition of the function I get `const test: <T>(obj: TypeA<T>) => T` (without null or undefined). This also means if I call it like this:

```
test<number>(someNullArg).toPrecision()
```

TypeScript doesn't complain, even though it should and even though the code throws a `Cannot read properties of null` error at runtime. If I replace the generic type the return type is correctly generated (`const test: (obj: TypeA<any>) => any | undefined | null`).

**Update**

Here's a simplified version of the actual implementation:

```
let value;

const get = <T>(obj: Promise<T>): T | undefined | null => {
  obj.then(val => value = val);
  return value;
}
```

It takes a Promise and returns its value (if it is resolved). It's designed to be used in [a StencilJS component](https://stenciljs.com) to output an asynchronous value in the synchronous render method. Basically I'm trying to recreate the functionality of [Angular's `async` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

**2nd Update**

I've tried to debug this further and I think this might be a bug in TypeScript.

I've reduced it to a simpler example:

```
function test<T>(): T | undefined | null {
  return (window as any).foo;
}

const x = test(); // type is "unknown"
const y = test<number>(); // type is "number"
y.toFixed(); // should throw a type error but doesn't
```

Apparently `| undefined | null` is completely ignored once the generic type is resolved and I don't know why since the return type is quite specific.

[Here's the entire source](https://gist.github.com/tricki/e897f3e40c15fd4dfa089a0c942acf18) (the important part is the `async` function).

Comment: What is `TypeA`?

Comment: What TypeA<T> does?

Comment: I've added an update to the question.

Comment: Are you using the  `—strictNullChecks` compiler option?

Comment: In `test`, `someArray[obj]` won't work because `obj` isn't guaranteed to be a number.  `get()` and `value` will always be `undefined` because `obj` is a `Promise` launched outside the function.  Are these unrelated pseudo-code problems?

Comment: @fedonev Yes, the first one is just because of pseudo-code, but I don't understand your second comment. Maybe I've simplified it too much but the code I have does actually work fine, the only problem I'm having is that TypeScript doesn't understand that the return value might be null or undefined.

Comment: @jcalz No, but when I activate it I (… got a bunch of wrong errors and) found that it fixes the return type but so does the answer Nalin Ranjan gave and I don't understand why.

Comment: If you are *not* using `--strictNullChecks` then `null` and `undefined` are automatically absorbed into any unions, they are essentially synonyms of `never`, see [here](https://tsplay.dev/wj48Mm).  You should really use `--strictNullChecks` if you want to use `null` and `undefined` as meaningful types.  If enabling that gives you a bunch of errors then you should clear them up separately (but that is out of scope of the question as asked).   I'm happy to write this up as an answer if you are likely to accept it.   Otherwise, let me know what questions remain unanswered.

Comment: I believe your mock `get` has a race condition because of the Promise handling.  `value` will be `undefined` unless you win the race.  Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7up7w).  I'm sure it's just a matter of your mock or my ignorance.

Comment: @fedonev You're right (I was actually surprised by this, I thought an already resolved promise would call the `then()` callback synchronously, but it doesn't) but in my case I actually force the Stencil component to rerender once the promise resolves so it gets the resolved value and therefore it calls the function again. If you're interested here's the code: https://gist.github.com/tricki/e897f3e40c15fd4dfa089a0c942acf18

Comment: @jcalz My intention is to open-source this for others to use and that's why I want the types to be explicit, and why I don't have control over the environment it will be used in. To me this seems like a bug since I would expect my very explicit type to be honored. If you can write an answer explaining why this is not a TS bug (or even a feature) I'll happily accept it (and use it as a basis for a bug report :))

Comment: "I would expect my very explicit type to be honored." The type `string | undefined` is equivalent to the type `string` if you have `--strictNullChecks` disabled, so the compiler reduces the former to the latter.  It's like you writing `3 + 0` and the compiler outputting `3` instead of `3 + 0`.  Can you articulate why `3 + 0` being written as `3` would be a *bug* as opposed to something you just don't like? In any case it's not a bug but maybe a feature request would be appropriate. I'll look to see if there are existing ones.

Comment: Looks like github is completely broken at the moment, so I will look for existing issues later, I guess. 

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the help . My thinking was that the config options might change the __implied__ type but that **specific types** still be honored. Is there any way I can indicate to users of this function that it might (and when using Promises definitely will) return `undefined` or `null`? Having to add it to the docs seems like a failing of TypeScript. Or would using the `strictNullChecks` config actually still work when this code is included in another app (with a different config)?

Comment: Anyone who cares about `null` and `undefined` should probably enable `--strictNullChecks` as that's the whole point of the feature.  I don't really know what will happen if you turn it off but people who include your code turn it on, or vice versa.  My suggestion is always to turn it on... and generally the entire [`--strict` suite of compiler features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict) to get a "standard" amount of type safety.  Then `null` and `undefined` will do exactly what you expect.  I'm still waiting for github to be completely alive to find related issues though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to deal with this properly, I'd suggest you enable [the `--strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strictNullChecks) and deal with any ensuing errors it flags. (I would go further and say to enable [the entire `--strict` suite of compiler features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict) to get a "standard" amount of type safety from the language.)  Indeed, the TypeScript handbook [says](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#strictnullchecks-off) "we always recommend people turn `strictNullChecks` on if it’s practical to do so in their codebase."

With `--strictNullChecks` off, [the `null` and `undefined` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined) are subtypes of every other type; any type `T` will accept a value of type `null` or `undefined`, and so forming a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `T` with `null` or `undefined` is equivalent to just `T`.  So `null` and `undefined` behave the same as [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), and are absorbed into all unions.  This is known as "subtype reduction" and something TypeScript does quite a bit.

Only with `--strictNullChecks` on does the compiler have any chance of tracking `null` and `undefined`.

---

You could make the argument that, if you are using [the `--declaration` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#declaration) to emit `.d.ts` declaration files to be used by others including your code as a module, the emitted declarations might not be accurate if the compiler eagerly reduces `T | null | undefined` to `T`, since the consuming applications might have `--strictNullChecks` *enabled*, and they would then be under the mistaken impression that `get()` always returns a `T` from a `Promise<T>` instead of possibly `undefined` or `null`.

And you'd be right.  This is considered a design limitation of TypeScript as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#18773](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18773).  As [mentioned there](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18773#issuecomment-332554857), "by the time we're emitting the `.d.ts` file, the `null`ness of any given type is long gone. We'd basically have to pretend [`--strictNullChecks`] was on as an entirely separate compile phase since it potentially changes any type result."  Since this would cause compile time to essentially double when `--strictNullChecks` is off and `--declaration` is on, they don't do it.

Since they can't fix this, you really should turn on `--strictNullChecks` if you're generating `.d.ts` files for your code.  Consumers who don't use `--strictNullChecks` wouldn't care one way or the other, but those who do will appreciate it.

---

Anyway, though, `null` and `undefined` being absorbed into unions when `--strictNullChecks` is disabled is working as intended and not a bug.  You *might* want to file a feature request to do this less eagerly so that `null` and `undefined` types are preserved in more situations, but I wouldn't expect the TS team to implement it, even if it's not immediately declined.

An issue that's similar in spirit is [microsoft/TypeScript#29729](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729), where a union containing `string` and other string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like `"a" | "b" | string` is subtype-reduced to just `string`.  Some people want `"a" | "b" | string` to stay as-is for autocomplete and documentation purposes, but the compiler sees `"a" | "b" | string` as ["a fancy way of writing `string`"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729#issuecomment-460346421).  So I'd expect any request of the form "make `T | null | undefined` stay as-is for documentation purposes" would be rejected or closed as a design limitation, with a note that `T | null | undefined` is just "a fancy way of writing `T`".  ‍♂️

Comment: Thanks for that extensive answer! I still don't fully understand it since until now I've been using TS rather casually and never really thought about the compiler config. But this is a good reason to read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

```
let value;

function get<T>(obj: Promise<T>): T | undefined | null {
  obj.then(val => value = val);
  return value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually fixes the return type! Do you know why? In my code the function is actually a property on an object (as in `const x = { get: <T>(obj: Promise<T>): T | undefined | null => { ... } }`) but using `function` doesn't help there.

Comment: I commented too early. The type definition when hovering in VSCode does now look correct but if I actually use the function (e.g. with the parameter being `declare const x: Promise<number> | undefined | null;`) and the generic is actually resolved (and not implicitly `unknown`) TS assumes there will always be a return value.